# Call Stored Procedure from DBeaver to DB2 not working

Tags: stored-procedures, dbeaver, dbvisualizer, db2-zos

I'm trying to call STP from DBeaver or Jmeter with the following command example:

```
@call SCHEMA.STPNAME(
  ${var_in1||AKTIVIER||String||dir=in noshow}$
, ${var_in2||AP||String||dir=in noshow}$
, ${var_in3||XXX||String||dir=in noshow}$
, ${var_out1||(null)||Integer||dir=out noshow}$
, ${var_out2||(null)||String||dir=out noshow}$
, ${var_out3||(null)||String||dir=out noshow}$
);
```

And I get the following message:
Unrecognized keyword in escape clause: var_in1||AKTIVIER||String||dir=in noshow. ERRORCODE: -4463, SQLSTATE:42601.

The strange thing is that in DBVisualizer it's working.
I'm using the same jar drivers for all the applications.